# How to reduce the number of revisions?

Tags: plugins, revisions

I some posts I have a lot of revisions, and I want only 2 revisions for each post.
I found this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revision-control/ that able to set that in the future WP will not store more then 2 revisions, but It does not remove existing revisions.
I found this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-delete-revision/ that can remove all the revisions. But I can not set to leave 2 revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `define ('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 2);`  in wp-config.php for two revisions, and you could turn that into your own plugin.

Manully remove all revisions with this query run in phpmyadmin:

> DELETE a,b,c FROM wp_posts a LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON
>   (a.ID = b.object_id) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
>   WHERE a.post_type = 'revision'

and then optimize.

Comment: I think that  `define ('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 2);` will not remove existing revisions. Right? And the query will remove all revisions -  I dont want to remove all revisions but I want to leave 2 revisions for each post

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revision-control/screenshots/ will leave the number of revisions you want and delete the rest.

Comment: By this way I have to take care about every post, one by one. I have more then 8,000 posts...

Comment: No, you don't; read the docs for the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add `define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 2 );` to your `wp-config.php`.

This'll limit to at most 2 revisions (you can also completely disable them with `false`).

Comment: This doesn’t affect existing revisions.

Comment: It will, the instant OP updates a post/page. Still, can use a plugin or SQL to wipe all existing.

Comment: It does not remove existing revisions. And I did not find any way to remove all revisions and to leave 2 revisions for each post.

Comment: How can we limit revisions on a wordpress.*com* blog?